Can category theory prove that the function is continuous?
Suppose I have an increasing sequence of integer intervals:$I_n=[0,b_n)$ for $b_n \lt b_{n+1}, \forall n \geq 1$ and a function sequence $f_n :\Bbb {Z} \to \Bbb{Z}$ such that on the intersection $I_n \cap I_{n+1} =I_n$ we have that $f_n(x) = f_{n+1}(x)  \ \forall x\in I_n$.   Additionally each $f_n$ is continuous in the coset (profinite) topology which comprises both their domain and codomain.
Define $f(x)= f_m(x)$ where $x\lt b_m$.  This is well defined.   Is $f$ continuous as well (in the coset topology)?

Category Theoretic Attempt.
Let $0 \in \Bbb{N}$.
Let $C$ be the category where objects are subsets of $\Bbb{Z}$ endowed with the profinite subspace topology, and maps are continuous maps.  These of course include incusion maps.  Also included are the $f_n$ and restrictions of each $f_n$ to $I_n$.  Let $\phi_n = f_n|_{I_n} : I_n \to \Bbb{Z}$.
The direct limit $$\lim_{\to} I_n = \Bbb{N}$$ clearly where the directed system is taken to be inclusion maps amongst the intervals.
Clearly the $\phi_n$ are compatible with the inclusion maps as $\phi_{n} = \phi_{n+1} \circ \iota_n$ where $\iota_n : I_n \to I_{n+1}$ by their compatibility at the intersections of the $I_n$.
Therefore by the UMP of direct limit, there exists a unique continuous map $f : \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{Z}$ such that $f \circ j_n = f_n$ on $I_n$ where $j_n : I_n \to \Bbb{N}$ is the canonical inclusion.
Question.
But how do we know that $f$ exists and is equal to my $f$ in the above (first paragraphs)?  And that its continuous? Thanks.

So you want to find a proof of the continuity of $f$ or a very special proof based on the direct limit?

@PaulFrost I'm curious, how else would you prove this other than direct limit?  I just think my category $C$ is wrong.  What should it be?  All topological spaces?

Why is $f$ well-defined for negative integers?

@KritikerderElche yes it is, I just restrict to $\Bbb{N}$ because that's all my application requires

@KritikerderElche it's defined for all $\Bbb{Z}$ in my application but the meaning of $f(-x)$ for $x \gt 0$ is up to debate.  I simply do not use these values in my application, though it's important that I kept it simple with Furstenberg's topology which is for all of the $\Bbb{Z}$.  When you take the subspace $\Bbb{N}$ you get the  $a\Bbb{N} + b$ for $0 \in \Bbb{N}$ defined.

I think you have to understand explicitly what the coset topology looks like. I doubt that general category theoretic arguments will suffice. But I may be wrong ...

@KritikerderElche why won't it work?  What about my direct limit?  I think all we need to do is replace $C$ with $\textbf{Top}$.  The topological ringness is only used to prove continuity of my individual $f_n$ (in my application), so we can do this in general $\textbf{Top}$ I think.  Can you confirm this?

No idea about it ...
